# In C++ how can I combine a search function and switch, so the switch can ask user to choose from search results and display information of result?

Tags: loops, search, switch-statement

1. The code asks user to pick a player from a team and it should display that players statistics. The search has to be able to do partial input searches as well. Here is the code I have came up with so far. But I am stuck between either the switch working correctly or the search function but cannot make them work together. Thanks for the help.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <fstream>

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
   int index = 0;
   int choice;
   int counter = 1;
   string player, result;


   cout << "\n\nThis program will ask the user for a player name from\n";
   cout << "the team Dallas Mavericks and give the statistics of the player.\n";
   cout << "  *Last Name First\n";
   cout << "  *Seperated By Comma\n";
   cout << "  *Use correct capitalization\n";
   cout << "Please enter player's name: ";
   getline(cin, player);

   ifstream inputFile;
   inputFile.open("statisticsMavs.txt");
   if (inputFile.fail())
   {
       cout << "Could not open file";
       return 1;
   }

   ofstream outputFile;
   outputFile.open("playerStats.txt");

   if (outputFile.fail())
   {
       cout << "Could not open file";
       return 1;
   }

   for (index = 0; getline(inputFile, result); index++) 
   {
       if (result.find(player) != string::npos)
       {
           cout << endl << counter++ << "  " << result.substr(0, 20) << endl;
           continue;
       }

       else
       {
           continue;
           cout << "Could not find player! Please enter another name: ";
           getline(cin, player);
       }
   }


   cout << "Please choose the number from the correct search result: ";
   cin >> choice;
   switch (choice)
   {
   case 1: outputFile << result << endl;
       return 1;
   case 2: outputFile << result << endl;
       return 1;
   case 3: outputFile << result << endl;
       return 1;
   case 4: outputFile << result << endl;
       return 1;
   default: cout << choice << " is not a valid input" << endl;
   }


   inputFile.close();
   outputFile.close();



   }
   ```

Comment: If they choose the player and you find it, they choose again because you might have two Smiths on the same team?

Comment: Oh, I see the issue. I bet it works fine if you match just 1. but if there are multiple matches, result only holds the last match. It feels like making result an array would help.

Comment: specifically move result to a new line and declare it string result[4]. Make getline(inputFile, result) getline(inputFile, result[counter-1]) index the the .find with [counter-1] and the subst with counter-2 and in each case (so as long as they said 1 to 4 you do not even need a switch) put out result[counter-1]

Comment: also, it seems to me you should not conclude you did not find the player until you are outside your loop.

Comment: Ok. I fixed the issued by moving it outside the loop. So is there no method to get the switch and search function to work together?

Comment: If you mean in one step, not as far as I know (but some other reader may know better). If you mean in stages, I think what I suggested about the array could work. And with that approach, so long as the index is in range, you wil not need a switch.

Comment: I created the array and implemented it the way you mentioned. But now it crashes directly after the search is performed while the choices are listed.

Comment: sorry for the hassle. Two ideas. add (counter<=4) || before getline. and read into some temporary string variable and only copy the matching ones into the results array. Does it crash even when there is just one choice?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the below, while not using switch, does get done what you were hoping, namely finding up to 4 matching results, then giving the one the person selected. Since I did not have the text files, I was not sure it works as is, but it compiles, and seems like it should. I tried to simplify where I could, while keeping the original intent (but I think where the original was off was that result held the last read matching string, so there was no way to choose an earlier one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
int choice;
int counter = 0;
string player, result;
string results[4];


cout << "\n\nThis program will ask the user for a player name from\n";
cout << "the team Dallas Mavericks and give the statistics of the player.\n";
cout << "  *Last Name First\n";
cout << "  *Seperated By Comma\n";
cout << "  *Use correct capitalization\n";
cout << "Please enter player's name: ";
getline(cin, player);

ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open("statisticsMavs.txt");
if (inputFile.fail())
{
    cout << "Could not open file";
    return 1;
}

ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open("playerStats.txt");

if (outputFile.fail())
{
    cout << "Could not open file";
    inputFile.close();
    return 1;
}

while ((counter<4) && getline(inputFile, result)) 
{
    if (result.find(player) != string::npos)
    {   
        results[counter++]=result;
        cout << endl << counter << "  " << result.substr(0, 20) << endl;

    }


}
if (counter == 0)
    {
        cout << "Could not find player! Terminating."<<endl;
    }
else
{
cout << "Please choose the number from the correct search result: ";
cin >> choice;

if ((choice>=1) && (choice<=counter))
{
    outputFile << results[choice-1] << endl;
    inputFile.close();
    outputFile.close();
    return 1;
}
else
{
cout << choice << " is not a valid input" << endl;
}
}

inputFile.close();
outputFile.close();



}
```